# How to make hgweb display repositories in a hierarchy?

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I have about 100 Mercurial repositories served by `hgweb`. The repositories are stored in a folder hierarchy, but `hgweb` displays the structure in a "flat" manner. This doesn't scale. Is there a way to display the repositories in a tree-like hierarchy instead?

Answer (score 3):

I like to organize my repos by type, this is what my hgweb config looks like:

```
[web]
baseurl =

[paths]
/apps = /var/hg/apps/*
/config = /var/hg/config/*
/design = /var/hg/design/*
/music = /var/hg/music/*
/projects = /var/hg/projects/*
/scripts = /var/hg/scripts/*
```

You can also use ** to make it display directories recursively.

```
[paths]
/ = /var/hg/**
```

Check out the docs for other details/options: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web.

You might also be interested in [RhodeCode](https://bitbucket.org/marcinkuzminski/rhodecode/src) which is a more feature-rich web interface for mercurial.

Comment: Latest beta of RHodeCode have repos group so it's perfect for managing larger amount of repositories

Comment: I thought * makes it display recursive directories and ** makes it display subrepositories?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this was an option at the time of the question, but there's now an option that enables descending into directories.

```
[web]
descend = True
```

You then have two options for how to configure your paths. If you specify a path with a single asterisk, it will descend into subdirectories until it finds repositories.

```
[paths]
/ = /var/hg/*
```

If you specify a path with two asterisks, it will also descend into repositories to see if there are nested repositories or subrepositories.

```
[paths]
/ = /var/hg/**
```

You can find more details on the Mercurial wiki at [PublishingRepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#hgweb%20Foo).

(It sounds as if you may also be looking to have the hierarchy displayed in a tree-like fashion. This solution only impacts which repositories will be detected. It will not change how they are displayed. I'm not aware of any built-in way to accomplish a hierarchical display.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved by enabling the `collapse` option:

```
[web]
collapse = yes
```